# Flexbox setting for cordova on samsung galaxy tab + android 4.1.2

Tags: android, css, cordova, flexbox

I'm struggling with flexbox css to style a cordova app on a galaxy tab + android 4.1.2

here is the css I use

```
.container {
    /*display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;*/
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    width: 83%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

and here is the result is the following

[image]

when I expect that

[image: enter link description here]

any idea why the css is different between the emulator and the real device?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    width: 83%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

made the trick